# Как нарисовать график matplotlib с экземплярами класса Pont

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть класс,который описывает точку на координатной плоскости и после должен отобразить массив этих точек на графике с помощью matplotlib

```py
class Point_6():
    """ Класс для точек на плоскости"""
    @property
    def coords(self):
        return self.__coord

    @ coords.setter
    def coords(self, value):
        if value < -100:
            self.__coord = 0
        elif value > 100:
            self.__coord = 0
        else:
            self.__coord = value

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        Point_6.count += 1

    def __del__(self):
        Point_6.count -= 1
        print("Object destroyed!")

    count = 0

    @staticmethod
    def display_count():  # Отображение количества точек
        print(f"Point count = {Point_6.count}")

    def display_point(self):  # Отображение точки
        print(f"Point({self.x}, {self.y})")

    def change_coords(self, offset_x, offset_y):
        self.x += offset_x  # Смещение х на offset_x
        self.y += offset_y  # Смещение y на offset_y
        print(f"Новые координаты точки после смещения ({self.x}, {self.y})")


def distance(point1, point2):  # Возвращает растояние между точками
    return ((point1.x - point2.x)**2 + (point1.y - point2.y)**2)**0.5


# Work with object
point_list = [Point_6(10, -2),
              Point_6(0, -7),
              Point_6(-4, 4),
              Point_6(-1, 5)]
for point in point_list:
    point.display_point()
dis = distance(point_list[1], point_list[3])
print(f"Растояние между второй и четвёртой точкой: {dis}")
point_list[2].change_coords(-21, 0)  # Смещение третьей точки на 21 влево


# work with plot
from matplotlib.pylab import *
for point in point_list:
    plot(point)
    grid()
    show()
```

Но по какой-то причине при запуске кода выдает следующую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как это исправить и корректно отобразить точки?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно Вы хотели сделать что-то такое:

```
class Point_6():
    """ Класс для точек на плоскости"""
    @property
    def coords(self):
        return self.__coord

    @ coords.setter
    def coords(self, value):
        if value < -100:
            self.__coord = 0
        elif value > 100:
            self.__coord = 0
        else:
            self.__coord = value

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        Point_6.count += 1

    def __del__(self):
        Point_6.count -= 1
        print("Object destroyed!")

    def getX(self):
        return self.x

    def getY(self):
        return self.y

    count = 0

    @staticmethod
    def display_count():  # Отображение количества точек
        print(f"Point count = {Point_6.count}")

    def display_point(self):  # Отображение точки
        print(f"Point({self.x}, {self.y})")

    def change_coords(self, offset_x, offset_y):
        self.x += offset_x  # Смещение х на offset_x
        self.y += offset_y  # Смещение y на offset_y
        print(f"Новые координаты точки после смещения ({self.x}, {self.y})")


def distance(point1, point2):  # Возвращает растояние между точками
    return ((point1.x - point2.x)**2 + (point1.y - point2.y)**2)**0.5


# Work with object
point_list = [Point_6(10, -2),
              Point_6(0, -7),
              Point_6(-4, 4),
              Point_6(-1, 5)]
for point in point_list:
    point.display_point()
dis = distance(point_list[1], point_list[3])
print(f"Растояние между второй и четвёртой точкой: {dis}")
point_list[2].change_coords(-21, 0)  # Смещение третьей точки на 21 влево


# work with plot
from matplotlib.pylab import *
points_x = []
points_y = []
for point in point_list:
    points_x.append(point.getX())
    points_y.append(point.getY())
scatter(points_x, points_y)
grid()
show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: выводит ошибку : **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/Labs/Lab4.py", line 68, in <module>
    points_x.append(point.getX())
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable**

Comment: @AlexRey, переведите ошибку и поймите где вы сделали что-то не так.